# Correct notation for rounding off numbers e.g. $201.7 \times 0.028 = 5.6476 = 5.6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What would be the correct notation to rounding off numbers:

**Option 1**
$$201.7 \times 0.028 = 5.6476 = 5.6$$

**Option 2**
$$201.7 \times 0.028 = 5.6476 \approx 5.6$$

PS: I am not sure I inserted the most appropriate tag for this question.

Thank you

Comment: It's obviously Option 2 since $5.6476 \ne 5.6$. If you want to use Option 1, you need to add 1 d.p or 2 s.f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second way

$$201.7 \times 0.028 = 5.6476 \approx 5.6$$

is to prefer unless we don't specify in some way that we are rounding the result to the first decimal digit.